# Custom post types + custom fields + custom taxonomy

Tags: wordpress

**WordPress 5.3.2**

**Custom Post Type UI 1.7.2**

I'm making a widget to rotate quotations of famous people.

Well, I made a custom post type quotation + special custom fields for it (quotation in English, URL of the source).

Then I made a custom taxonomy (author, position of the the author).

Now I'd like to select 10 last quotations with all information about their authors.

But when I looked at what there is in the database, I was a bit astonished: there is JSON there.
Like this:

```
a:7:{s:4:"type";s:3:"url";s:12:"instructions";s:0:"";s:8:"required";i:0;s:17:"conditional_logic";i:0;s:7:"wrapper";a:3:{s:5:"width";s:0:"";s:5:"class";s:0:"";s:2:"id";s:0:"";}s:13:"default_value";s:0:"";s:11:"placeholder";s:0:"";}
```

[image]

Could you help me understand whether there is an elegant solution how to extract 10 last quotations with information about their authors? I understand that I provided not exact information. But could you give me a most general piece of advice on where to read on this or something like that. Then I'd be able t localize the problem more exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Get your post content in a variable & unserialize the data into an array like this and use it....

```
 $data = get_post_field('post_content', get_the_ID());

 $test = unserialize($data);
 var_dump($test);
```